# PHP/SQL - compare a lot of images

Tags: php, sql, image, compare

I create a script which will be magazine a lot of images into database. I want magazine only unique images so I should checking everytime if now getting image exist in my database. And this is my problem - how I can do it in short time, when in my database is ~1000000 records?

My idea is use strlen() on every image:

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://server.com/imageX.jpg');
$counter = strlen($image);
// $counter => for example: 105188
```

Then save this number in database and use INSERT IGNORE INTO:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `database` (`unique_counter`, `img_url`, `img_name`) VALUES (105188, 'http://server.com/imageX.jpg', 'imageX.jpg')
```

and if this image will be added - everything is ok. But I think this idea is well for ~100 images. When I have 1000000 images and more and everything of these images have similar sizes (width and height), counter from my idea can be the same also when images will be not the same.

Can you help? How I can compare many images from my database in very short time?

Thanks.

Comment: Dont use filesize, hash it instead with md5/sha1, not only that the URL would be unique.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone but it still idea from my first post - get image, hash it and then count - I think when I have 1.000.000+ images, this way is not well for me because it could reject images which aren't in my database but have the same long value.

Comment: hashing with say md5 will give 2^32 chance of collision, a filesize wont.

Comment: You want to detect uniqueness in a binary file? This is only possible by reading both files and comparing them. You can shortcut this however. File size is one idea to only have to compare files of the same size. hash codes is another. Must file names match? File date? EXIF data? It boils down to this: The more data you store the less files you must compare. If you store a hash code of two bytes there are only 2^16 different values, if you store a hash code of 20 bytes, there are 2^160 values. Much less collisions hence, but still, every now and then you may have to compare the files.

Comment: yes as @LawrenceCherone mentioned. `md5` length is 32. So you do not need to worry about the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a hash for that images then you can store them into the database.

you can use `$hash = md5_file($file_path);` to get hash for smaller files

If you have very large image and you can get hash without affecting the memory limit

```
function get_hash($file_path, $limit = 0, $offset = 0) {

    if (filesize($file_path) < 15728640) { //get hash for less than 15MB images
        // md5_file is always faster if we don't chunk the file
        $hash = md5_file($file_path);

        return $hash !== false ? $hash : null;
    }

    $ctx = hash_init('md5');

    if (!$ctx) {
        // Fail to initialize file hashing
        return null;
    }

    $limit = filesize($file_path) - $offset;

    $handle = @fopen($file_path, "rb");
    if ($handle === false) {
        // Failed opening file, cleanup hash context
        hash_final($ctx);

        return null;
    }

    fseek($handle, $offset);

    while ($limit > 0) {
        // Limit chunk size to either our remaining chunk or max chunk size
        $chunkSize = $limit < 131072 ? $limit : 131072;
        $limit -= $chunkSize;

        $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSize);
        hash_update($ctx, $chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);

    return hash_final($ctx);
}
```

Comment: So I should get image code from url, then hash it (md5, sha etc) and save this hash in my database. Then compare only this hashes, ye? And this is the best idea for me?

Comment: exactly, it works great. We have running an application which does the same thing for millions of files and images

Answer (score 0):

```
$info = getimagesize('http://server.com/imageX.jpg');

$info['time'] = time();// You can add microtime if needed..

$hash = base64_encode(json_encode($info));

INSERT IGNORE INTO `database` (`hash`, `img_url`, `img_name`) VALUES ($hash, 'http://server.com/imageX.jpg', 'imageX.jpg')
```